# How to map a key for a specific file

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, autocmd

We can use the `FileType` autocommand event to create a customized key mapping for a specific type of file. For example, <kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> could call different build tools for a Java file compared to a C++ file.

I wonder is there any way to create a customized key mapping for a specific file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `BufRead` event in combination with a buffer-local mapping. For example, if I want <kbd>o</kbd> in Normal mode to echo `Math is rad` only when I'm editing a file named `foo.bar`:

```
autocmd BufRead foo.bar nnoremap <buffer> o :echo "Math is rad"<CR>
```

See:

```
:h autocmd-events
:h BufRead
:h autocmd-patterns
:h map-local
```